Passing Client side info to Login in Blazor Web app
I have a scenario, which worked previosuly in Blazor, but not in Blazor 9 (& 8) with the new Web app template & Identity.
I have a basked Id, stored on the client side in LocalStorage - at this point this is an anonymous basket.  When a user logs in, I need to merge his anonymous basket with his saved 'live' basket (may have been populated on another device).
The basket merge ideally would happen on Login.  But the anonymous basket Id is on the client and you can't use LocalStorage in the new server based Identity Login component. I also don't see a way to pass the basket key to login as any [Authorize] page may have redirected to login.
I might be missing something but can't see the way to handle it.  Ideally I want to do the merge in a login success event handler - but I can't get that in the client components - maybe I'm missing how do do that.  Otherwise I need to make the basket key avaialable in the session on the server.
Any ideas as to acheive this?
